# Laravel Eloquent withcount compared to other model attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model named

```
timeslot.
```

this model has an attribute (integer) named

```
requested_participants
```

This model has also a relationship in order to attach participants :

```
public function participants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Human::class, 'humans_timeslots', 'timeslot_id', 'human_id');
    }
```

I want to retrieve records that have less

```
participants
```

than

```
requested_participants
```

I tried things like :

```
Timeslot::withCount('participants')
                            ->having('participants_count','<','requested_resources')
                            ->get();
```

But this doesn't work !

It works if I use an integer instead of

```
requested_resources
```

like :

```
Timeslot::withCount('participants')
                            ->having('participants_count','<',2)
                            ->get();
```

but not with this attribute which is part of the same model. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is there an error when using the `requested_resources` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `havingRaw` method:

```
Timeslot::withCount('participants')
->havingRaw('participants_count < requested_resources')
->get();
```